# how to avoid both onItemClick and onCreateContextMenu from being called

Tags: android, callback, android-listview, android-view

My Activity uses a ListView.  I would like to do X when the user long-taps an item and Y when he normal-taps.  My onCreate() contains code like:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
registerForContextMenu(mListView);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that when the user long-taps on an item, both onCreateContextMenu() and onItemClick() are called.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have tested it and context menu is called only on long press and onclick only listview click item event takes place

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListViewExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] STATES = new String[] { "Haryana", "Punjab", "Rajasthan",
        "Maharashtra", "Madhya Pradesh", "Kerala", "Jammu","Bihar","Karnataka" , "TamilNadu",
                "Uttar Pradesh" ,"Gujrat"};
View listColor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,STATES));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setBackgroundColor(getTitleColor());
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if(listColor!=null){
                listColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                listColor=view;
            }else{

                listColor=view;

            }
            Log.i("called", "item click");
            listColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
           //on click of any item the item name will be shown in toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Log.i("called", "Context menu");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Context menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `OnItemLongClickListener` to `null` for the list view seems to do the trick, leaving the long press handling to show the context menu:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
registerForContextMenu(mListView);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(null);
```

If this feels too hacky to set the `OnItemLongClickListener` to `null`, you can also set it to an `OnLongClickListener` that returns `false`, signaling that the long click was not consumed.

```
mListView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return false;
  }
});
```